# Find a generator of a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I think I may have a question which will help not only me but also somebody in the future.

The question is related to cyclic groups. I always struggle with the following problem assume that I have a multiplication table lets for some values $a,b,c$. I wish to check whether $a$ is the generator of the group.

I write: $$\langle a\rangle = \{ \dots, a^{-3}, a^{-2},a^{-1},a^0,a^1,a^2,a^3, \dots   \}.$$

> So I know what is $a^3, a^2,a^1$ because $a^3 $ is simply $a\times a\times a$ and I check in my table what it is but what would be $ a^0 $, the identity of a group? What would be the negative powers of $a$ how to understand, interpret it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your question "Given a group $(G,*)$ and an element $a \in G$, how do we define the subgroup generated by $a$ (denoted $<a>$)" ?

If so, since $G$ is a group, every element has an inverse, hence $a^{-1}$ is just the inverse of $a$ in the group $(G,*)$ and $a^{-n}= a^{-1}* \dots *a^{-1}$ is just the multiplication of $a^{-1}$, $n$ times. 
By convention $a^0:=e$ is the neutral element of $G$.

$<a>= \{ a^n, \ n \in \Bbb Z \}$ is a well defined subgroup of $G$ (and it's easy to see that it's the smallest subgroup containing $a$).

We say that $a$ generates $G$ if $G= <a>$.

Comment: that is what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: It may worth noting that, being settled what does $g^n$ mean for $n≥1$ and that $g^{−n}:=(g^{−1})^n$, then by *defining* $g^0:=e$ the property $g^ng^{−m}=g^{n−m}$ holds also for $m=n$ and then for every $n$ and $m$.